How can I setup default editor for using Git?
In windows ,choosing default editor can be VIM, Visual studio code , Wordpad, Notepad.
What is the difference in this all editor while using Git.
which could be the ideal default editor while using git.(for a beginner user using git)

If your are using vs code then it would be ideal

Do you mean to ask "Which editor is best to use with git?"

if you are using vs code, then it would be ideal
The major difference between vim, vs code, notepad is pace of writing and interface. Vim has terminal based interface. On the other hand vs code and notepad are graphical interface.
I would recommend to use the IDE you are using, here i assumed you are using vs code.
Open terminal and run this command to set default editor
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"

